# how to Decide shipping cost for Ecommerce site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, e-commerce

I am developing a E commerce website I am confuse about shipping cost because any person from all over the world can purchase products but at this time how can we decide the shipping cost ?

Comment: check with whatever courier service you will be using?

Comment: @tinkerbot ok thank you and this question is useful or i should delete it ?

Comment: It isn't really in the right place, given that it has nothing to do with code

Comment: @Qwerky this questions is a _very_ bad fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Seems to me like the OP is asking about requirements. The question is pretty general, but that's OK. Maybe it could be worded a bit better, like "How do I gather requirements to model shipping costs", but to me it is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways that a ***programmer*** could set this up based on the merchant needs and scale...

1) The simplest -- merchants can assign rates per pound based on location and the service level (standard, expedited, etc). the advantage is you aren't having to get rates from another party during checkout so its simpler.

OR 2) - as part of the checkout process - you are pinging a specific shipper like FedEx to get the rates and then calculating cost based on the weight in the shopping cart, and then shipping it FedEx.

OR 3) - similar but you are pinging a service which handles different shipping services, getting back multiple rates, and then present the customer with different costs and shipping options.

OR 4) - merchant is using a fulfillment service that warehouses the goods in multiple locations. when the customer checks out, e-commerce site pings  the fulfillment service which figures out shipping costs based on the closest warehouse to the customer.

note on option 3 - many of these services make the programming and integration much simpler and faster then integrating directly with a shipping service. in other words even if you have a relatively small merchant and you are only starting with one shipping service like FedEx -- it can still be worthwhile to integrate with a service that handles multiple shipping services for the faster integration and added admin tools.